# Can I override the “nil” variables in .dir-locals.el with a more specific mode?

Tags: directory-local-variables

There is a project called Piglit with a `.dir_locals.el` [file](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/piglit/tree/.dir-locals.el) like this:

```
((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)))
 (python-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil))))
```

I think the intention is that most files in the project should use `indent-tabs-mode` but Python files should not. However this doesn’t seem to work. As far as I can tell the definition for the `nil` mode overrides the definition for the Python mode and Emacs enables tab indentation for Python files. Is there any way to correctly implement the intended behaviour?

Comment: I notice that that project also has an `.editorconfig` file.  I have seen an instance before where that was interfering with the other tab settings in emacs.  This may or may not be an instance in this case.  I will have to try and reproduce the issue myself.

Comment: This is a good opportunity, I guess, to advertise the Emacs development mailing list: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-11/msg00209.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experimentally, I think Emacs is using the *first* match it finds.  So if you re-arrange spec to put the `nil` case last, you'll end up with the desired outcome.

```
((python-mode . ((indent-tabs-mode . nil)))
 (nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t))))
```

I feel this is a change of behaviour, and possibly a bug.  It's not flagged in NEWS in any case.

---

Edit: Ok, definitely a bug.

It turns out that it *was* previously also the case that the sequence mattered (I never noticed, as I always put the nil case first); but the priority order seems to have flipped in 26.1.

So I think it used to be the case that the *last* match had final say, whereas in 26.1 the *first* match has final say.  Which is clearly a bad change when it comes to the compatibility of dir-locals files across different versions of Emacs.

Could you please `M-x report-emacs-bug` about this?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. It seems to already work on git master. I bisected the fix down to this commit https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit?id=97b7e58c4d34722e8b0eb73b3ed315fdc9671264 . It doesn’t seem like the fix was deliberate. Hmm

Comment: I filed the bug here https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33400